# Set-cookie header is present but cookies are not set, no HttpOnly

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, fetch-api

I'm trying to get cookies via `document.cookies` (session id) in the console after receiving them here:

[image: responce header]

As you see no HttpOnly is present. But cookies still are not accessible for some reason.

I'm using `whatwg-fetch` in react app for queries. Chrome browser, Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit), but tested with others and no luck as well

Answer (score 0):

okay, the thing was that I cannot use cookies while working with wildcard allow access origin requests.